# How can I process this form alone?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have this function on an html form, the form script there is this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var conf = {
       isVip:false,
       isMem:false
    };
</script>
```

and here is the the button, the button is to process two form in the html, here is the button.

```
   <li class="current">
      <a href="#" onclick="return false;">formlogin</a>
    </li>
   <li>
   <a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="vip"></span>VIPsubmit</a>
  </li>
  <a href="#" class="loginBtn"
```

Here is the form

```
   <form name="vip_login" method="post" action="process.php">
    <input tabindex="1" id="vipname" type="text" class="username" name="username" value=""/><span class="vipDomain">@name.com</span>
   <input  tabindex="2"  id="vippassword" type="password" class="password" name="password" value=""/>
```

My question is, how do I make the btn to process my form alone and send data to external process.php function.